# Compiler errors during port of application from qt 4.3.5 to qt 5.2.1

Tags: c++, qt

I'm porting a c++ Dll with MSVC 2010 from 32- to 64 bit.
Therefore I changed the qt version it uses from qt 4.3.5 to qt 5.2.1.
It seems, that they changed some things, because I receive the following errors when I try to compile:

- cpp(116): error C2039: 'latin1' : is not a member of 'QString'
- cpp(477): error C2039: 'extension' : is not a member of 'QFileInfo'
- cpp(518): error C2660: 'QFileInfo::baseName' : function does not take 1 arguments
- cpp(824): error C2039: 'setIcon' : is not a member of 'QWidget'

I've looked in the qt porting guidelines, but didn't find anything specific to the above problems.
Any hints welcome.

Comment: Don't look in porting guidelines. Look in the documentation for those members.

Answer (score 0):

I think, all mentioned functions come from Qt3 and were in Qt4 along with Qt3Support libraries for compatibility reasons. What you need to do now, is just replacing them with equivalent functions from Qt5 API. For example:

```
QWidget::setIcon() -> QWidget::setWindowIcon()
QFileInfo::extension() -> QFileInfo::suffix()
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. You are right. The dll formerly had an enhanced functionality that made the q3support necessary. But after removing this functionality I also removed the q3support lib and the projects still compiles with 32 bit and qt4.3.5. So I don't understand why it doesn't work when I switch to the 64 Bit configuration with qt 5.2.1